# Jags: How to create vector with probabilities that are based on one of its outcomes?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, jags

I am very new to Jags. I just started using it for my stats class. I have done other types of programming, but I am having trouble understanding how to use Jags properly.

Right now, I have a vector face_probabilities, representing a dice:

face_probabilities[1] <- 1/6

face_probabilities[2] <- 1/6

face_probabilities[3] <- 1/6

face_probabilities[4] <- 1/6

face_probabilities[5] <- 1/6

face_probabilities[6] <- 1/6

My question is, how do I modify it to something like the following? I want to make x equal the the probability of rolling a 6 and every other possibility equal to x/2. However, the following code doesn't work.

face_probabilities[1] <- x/2

face_probabilities[2] <- x/2

face_probabilities[3] <- x/2

face_probabilities[4] <- x/2

face_probabilities[5] <- x/2

face_probabilities[6] <- x

I apologize if this is a dumb question, I am unsure of where to go to start learning Jags, I would appreciate it if I could be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

It will help you a lot if you don't try to think of BUGS/JAGS as a programming language - it isn't a programming language, and doesn't really behave like one.  The main difference is that each node must be defined (on the left hand side of a <- or ~) EXACTLY once.

In the code you displayed, 'x' isn't defined anywhere, so you should have got an error telling you that.  Maybe you wanted to define x in the data?

JAGS is very similar to BUGS, which has been around a bit longer and has more self-help stuff available.  I'd start by looking online for some introductions to WinBUGS and see if that helps you get going.

Good luck!

Matt